# pluploadQueue check file size before upload and block

Tags: jquery, file, size, plupload

I know that in pluploadQueue i can limit file size like this setting "max_file_size : '2mb'".
But want to upload different types of files, like images and videos.
And i want to check a different file size for each type, is it possible?
Maybe in an event before upload i can get that information and alert and stop the upload?

Thx in advanced,
Miguel

Comment: You may start with http://stackoverflow.com/a/15520225/1236044 . In FilesAdded, cycle the files collection starting from the end. For each file, check its extension and its size. If it is not ok, call the splice function (removeFile may also do the trick) Check the plupload API http://www.plupload.com/plupload/docs/api/index.html