# Limit the number of uploads in plupload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, plupload

My client is using an old classipress version, here's a [github repo](https://github.com/wp-premium/classipress) I found but what he's using is much older. Running the latest Wordpress version. It comes with [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/), some old version, couldn't find the version in the theme. Here's [Functions.php](https://github.com/wp-premium/classipress/blob/master/functions.php), here's [plupload](https://github.com/wp-premium/classipress/tree/master/includes/plupload). [Here's the html of my page,](https://pastebin.com/EtWr4rb6) no need to see it, but i'm putting it there because the page is protected so that's the only way to inspect the whole code if you want to.

I want to add the ability to upload multiple pictures at the same time, to do that, I add [this](http://classipro.com/upload-multiple-images-at-once-in-classipress/) to functions.php

```
add_filter('appthemes_plupload_config', 'enable_plupload_multisel', 10 ,1);
function enable_plupload_multisel($app_plupload_config){
$app_plupload_config['plupload']['multi_selection'] = true;
return $app_plupload_config; }
```

But I don't know how to stop the user from uploading more than 8 pictures? I tried adding `max_files` and `max_files_count` and `max_file_count` and nothing worked, I even modified the source code of the plugin itself and the js and nothing worked. I want to stop the user from being able to upload more than 8 images.

After I gave up on plupload, I tried doing it using Jquery, again didn't work

```
 /* prevent form submission if user selects more than 8 pics */
 jQuery('#app-attachment-upload-pickfiles').change(function() {
     if (this.files.length > 8) {
         alert('Uploading more than 8 images is not allowed');
         this.value = '';
     }
 });
 // Prevent submission if limit is exceeded.
 jQuery('#mainform').submit(function() {
     if (this.files.length > 8) {
         jQuery('#app-attachment-upload-pickfiles').hide();
         jQuery('#step1').hide();
         return false;
     } else {
         jQuery('#app-attachment-upload-pickfiles').show();
         jQuery('#step1').show();
     }
 });
```

**Edit**

My [pluploadjs here](https://pastebin.com/p7iZgFg2). `FilesAdded`

```
    attachUploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up, files) {
        jQuery.each(files, function(i, file) {
            jQuery('#app-attachment-upload-filelist').append(
                '<div id="' + file.id + '" class="app-attachment-upload-progress">' +
                file.name + ' (' + plupload.formatSize(file.size) + ') <b></b>' +
                '</div>');

            window.appFileCount += 1;
            APP_Attachment.hideUploadBtn();
        });

        up.refresh();
        attachUploader.start();
    });
```

I modified it to look like so

```
    attachUploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up, files) {
        var maxfiles = 8;
            if(up.files.length > maxfiles )
             {
                up.splice(maxfiles);
                alert('no more than '+maxfiles + ' file(s)');
             }
            if (up.files.length === maxfiles) {
                $('#app-attachment-upload-filelist').hide("slow"); // provided there is only one #uploader_browse on page
            }
        jQuery.each(files, function(i, file) {
            jQuery('#app-attachment-upload-filelist').append(
                '<div id="' + file.id + '" class="app-attachment-upload-progress">' +
                file.name + ' (' + plupload.formatSize(file.size) + ') <b></b>' +
                '</div>');

            window.appFileCount += 1;
            APP_Attachment.hideUploadBtn();
        });

        up.refresh();

        attachUploader.start();
    });
```

Is that all? Will it work now? I haven't tested it because it will give errors

Comment: I tried asking on plupload forum http://www.plupload.com/punbb/register.php it says `This forum is not accepting new registrations. Post your questions to StackOverflow instead (with a tag "plupload").` I tried asking on github too, I hope to get an answer

Comment: this may help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/15520225/1236044

Comment: @jbl please read my edit and tell me if it would work now

Comment: well, perfoming a jQuery.each on a collection which may just have been spliced does not seem correct.
A way to test : http://www.plupload.com/docs/v2/Create-a-Fiddle

Comment: @jbl tried it, nothing is working, maybe there's some function in wordpress. I don't know I give up

Comment: your JQuery.each should take `up.files` and not `files` as first parameter.
Also `window.appFileCount += 1;` may produce erratic behaviour

Comment: @jbl I guess so because the answer given almost worked

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but your code should almost work. I think you should manually remove the files from the queue by calling the `removeFile` method.

Maybe try this code:

```
    attachUploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up, files) {
        var maxfiles = 8;

        // remove all new files after the max of files
        jQuery.each(up.files, function(i, file) {
            if(i > maxfiles){
                up.removeFile(file);
            }
        });      
});
```

Comment: almost there, worked once however i still have this https://pastebin.com/04UDCBxY

Comment: That's an stacktrace, so you should be able to trace it back to the exact line of code where this happens. Probably where you use and 'id' of an undefnined object . Make sure you don't use the file object that was already removed.

Comment: will try it later, I give you the bounty because it was going to expire and I don't have time to test it